# Whats the difference between a socket which is open and a socket which is connected?

Tags: java, sockets, datagram, closesocket

The Java `Socket` class has two methods `isClosed` and `isConnected` to check whether the socket is closed or connected respectively. I wanted to know what's the difference between a TCP socket which is only open and a TCP socket which is open and connected, and how is this different from UDP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To put things simply, a `Socket` that is *open* is a socket that is either waiting for connection or has successfully connected with another `Socket`. When a socket has been *closed*, it means that this socket is no longer available for connection, and that it's resources has already been released. A `Socket` that is connected, well, it means that the socket is connected to another `Socket`.

So a `Socket` can..

- be open and connected at the same time.
- be open and not connected at the same time.
- not be connected when closed.

**UPDATE**

from @Bryan

Apparently, there are *half-closed* or *half-open* states for TCP Sockets; which usage (today) is different from its original meaning. More on this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/298919/what-is-tcp-half-open-connection-and-tcp-half-closed-connection).

Comment: Not to confuse things, but TCP also has a half-closed state where there is still a connection but it's now unidirectional.

Answer (score 7):

This page gives a fairly good overview on socket states: http://diranieh.com/SOCKETS/SocketStates.htm and the difference between TCP and UDP sockets. Particularly:

- State "Open" (TCP and UDP): An unnamed socket has been created. An unnamed socket is one that is not bound to a local address and port
- State "Connected" (TCP only): An association (virtual circuit) has been established between a local and remote host. Sending and receiving data is now possible.

Note that newer implementations of java.net.DatagramSocket support an extension to the TCP/IP network states: A DatagramSocket can also be in the state "connected", so that isConnected() does not necessarily return false even though a datagram socket is never "connected" at the network layer. In particular: *"When a DatagramSocket is connected to a remote address, packets may only be sent to or received from that address. By default a datagram socket is not connected."*

For more information, see the [sources](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.java.html) and the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#connect%28java.net.InetAddress,%20int%29).