# Why does java.net.DatagramSocket support a "connected" state?

Tags: java, sockets, datagram

In reference to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685056/whats-the-difference-between-a-socket-which-is-open-and-a-socket-which-is-connec): What is the background that a java.net.DatagramSocket supports a "connected" state?

I would have expected that the isConnected() method always returns false, since UDP/datagram sockets [do not support a connected state](http://diranieh.com/SOCKETS/SocketStates.htm). But a quick look at the [sources](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.java.html) shows that there is some logic behind the isConnected() method. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the Javadoc. When you "connect" a `DatagramSocket` to a remote IP/port you are just telling the socket not to accept packets to or from any other remote host.

Comment: So, simply said, this is an extension to the underlying network protocol states, and the connected state of DatagramSocket has nothing to do with network level states, right?

Comment: And also to only send to that remote host:ip.